# Code to find records from tableA which are not available in tableB

Tags: mysql, sql

I want if i search for courier_id = 950 then it will take only those order which are not in order rejected table against courier_id = 950

**for ex** -

If i search for courier_id = 950 the it will take only order id 852,853 bcoz this is not in order rejected table against courier_id = 950

please see below example

**EX : -**

**Orders table**

```
id, ordername
850   test1
851   test2
852   test3
853   test4
```

**order Rejected tables**

```
id,courier_id,order_id
1    950        850
2    950        851
3    951        853
```

**Expected output**

**Orders table**

```
id, ordername
852   test3
853   test4
```

**Below is my query**

```
SELECT o.id
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN order_rejected_details r ON o.id = r.order_id
WHERE r.courier_id != 950
```

Comment: SELECT o.* FROM orders o LEFT JOIN rejected r ON o.id = r.id WHERE r.id IS NULL should do the job.

Comment: did you tried `r.id IS NULL` condition ?

Comment: i want if i search for courier_id = 950 then it will take only those order which are not in order rejected table against courier_id = 950
  for ex - if i search for courier_id = 950 the it will take only order id 852,853 bcoz this is not in order rejected table against courier_id = 950

Answer (score 1):

Using left join you must pass the condition into `WHERE` clause to `ON` clause

```
SELECT o.id
FROM orders o
  LEFT JOIN order_rejected_details r 
    ON o.id = r.order_id AND r.courier_id != 950
```

**[UPDATE]**

After I read the comment, I believe that the correct query is using subquery:

```
SELECT o.id
FROM orders o
WHERE
    o.id NOT IN (
      SELECT r.order_id 
      FROM order_rejected_details r 
      WHERE r.courier_id = 950
    )
```

Comment: You've used a left join and haven't included a where statement. You're going to retrieve every id in the orders table.

Comment: I've change the answer to use subquery searching all orders that id is not in rejected with courier_id = 950.

Answer (score 0):

Use a LEFT JOIN and filter on the NULLs.

```
SELECT o.id, o.ordername
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN order_rejected_details r ON r.order_id = o.id AND r.courier_id = 950
WHERE r.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition eliminates the rows with null values. Hence an extra constraint must be added.
Either,

```
SELECT o.id, o.order_name FROM orders o LEFT JOIN orders_rejected r ON o.id = r. order_id 
WHERE r.courier_id != 950 OR r.courier_id IS NULL
```

or,

```
SELECT o.id, o.order_name FROM orders o LEFT JOIN orders_rejected r ON o.id = r. order_id 
AND r.courier_id = 950 WHERE r.courier_id IS NULL
```

In the former code, the rows are joined first and then rows with 'id != 950' are eliminated. While in the latter code, the rows with 'id != 950' are eliminated while joining.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this query for your purpose.

```
SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE `order_id` NOT IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(r.order_id)) FROM order_reject r GROUP BY r.order_id )
```

Comment: You haven't used his filter(950) and GROUP_CONCAT is going to return a comma separated string? I don't see how that's going to work.